# Adding items according to object's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

This is the code i currently have:

```
//Create offer makes a new object
var offer = manager.createOffer(steamID)

//The items i have in cart
var cart = {
    "Scrap Metal": 2
}

//The json file that holds all the assetid
var data = {
    "Scrap Metal": {
        "appid": "440",
        "contextid": "2",
        "assetid": [
            "123456",
            "234567",
            "345678",
            "546789"
        ]
    }
}

var itemInCart = Object.keys(cart)
for(i=0 ; i< itemInCart.length; i++){
offer.addMyItem({
    "appid": data[itemInCart[i]].appid,
    "contextid": data[itemInCart[i]].contextid,
    "assetid": data[itemInCart[i]].assetid

    })
}

//Offer's output should be like this
[{
    "appid": "440",
    "contextid": "2",
    "assetid": "123456"
},{
    "appid": "440",
    "contextid": "2",
    "assetid": "234567"
}]
```

*Edited for better understanding on what i want(hopefully :V) Which means if the `cart` object item's value is 2 it will add 2 new object into offer but with different assetids

Comment: please clear one thing, in final `offer object`, do you want `assetid` to be an array or do you want to add two object with different `assetid`, based on the value the item have in the cart like: `{ scarp metal: 2 }`, so you want 2 object to be added in offer with first two asset id respectively in each object?

Comment: yes, i want it to add the ammount of assetid depending on the cart object

Comment: sorry, I am unable to fully understand you. Please [choose one of these](https://pastebin.com/iENM07Yn) or explain a little bit more.

Comment: offer 2, but i want to add same items with different assetid to offer according to cart object, like say cart `{"scrap": 2}` and i want it to add 2 different assetid of scrap metal

Comment: I believe, `offer_2` has a different `assetid`, and my answer does the same thing.!!

Comment: object cart has `{"scrap metal": 2}` i want it to add items based on the value

`offer.addMyItem({
            "assetid": items[itemInCart[i]].assetid,
            "appid": items[itemInCart[i]].appid,
            "contextid": items[itemInCart[i]].contextid
        })`  this will add only 1 scrap metal which is assetid[0] the cart object says 2, which means i want it to add asset[0] and assetid[1]

Comment: if you will see my answer, i haven't used `"assetid":items[itemInCart[i]].assetid`, I have used the `array slice` to get the first `n` elements of the `assetid` array. Please read the code in my answer and press the `run code snippet` button to see the result of the code.

Comment: doesnt seems like what i wanted

Comment: can you please update the question with exactly what you want as the result? you can refer this link. https://pastebin.com/iENM07Yn

Comment: edited the post, hopefully you guys will get it :V

Comment: you actually you wanted `offer_1` from the link i have given, against what you have [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897459/adding-items-according-to-objects-value/45897638#comment78762492_45897459). Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array `slice`, to get the first `n` elements of the array. [Read More about slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var items = {
  "Scrap Metal": {
    "market_hash_name": "Scrap Metal",
    "appid": 440,
    "contextid": "2",
    "assetid": [
      "6090807122",
      "6090807127",
      "6090807143",
      "6090807132",
      "6090807183",
      "6090807173",
      "6090807167",
      "6090807160",
      "6090807154"
    ]
  }
}

var cart = {
  "Scrap Metal": 4
}

var manager = {
  result: [],
  createOffer: function(thing) {
    return {
      addMyItem: function(obj) {
        manager.result = [ ...manager.result, obj ];
      },
      get: function(obj) {
        return manager.result;
      }
    };
  }
}

var offer = manager.createOffer();

Object.keys(cart).forEach( cartItem => {

  if (items[cartItem].assetid.length < cart[cartItem]) {
    console.log('dont have enough asset id');
  }

  items[cartItem].assetid.slice(0, cart[cartItem]).forEach( assetid => {
    
    offer.addMyItem({
      "assetid": assetid,
      "appid": items[cartItem].appid,
      "contextid": items[cartItem].contextid
    })
  })


})

console.log(offer.get());
```

Since in the sample code above, I have used `"Scrap Metal": 4`.It will yield the result as given below, with first 4 asset id in the resulting object.

```
[
  {
    "assetid": "6090807122",
    "appid": 440,
    "contextid": "2"
  },
  {
    "assetid": "6090807127",
    "appid": 440,
    "contextid": "2"
  },
  {
    "assetid": "6090807143",
    "appid": 440,
    "contextid": "2"
  },
  {
    "assetid": "6090807132",
    "appid": 440,
    "contextid": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: This isnt what i want,  i have a 2 in the object cart and i want to add 2 asset id of the same item

Comment: I have added a snippet, so that you can test the code here, and upon what you have told in comments above, I believe this code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```html
for (i = 0; i < itemInCart.length; i++) {
  items[itemInCart[i]].assetid.forEach(function(aid){
        offer.addMyItem({
            "assetid": items[itemInCart[i]].assetid,
            "appid": items[itemInCart[i]].appid,
            "contextid": aid
        })  
  })

 }
```

Comment: items[itemInCart[i]].contextid.forEach(function(cid){   contextid ? do you mean assetid ?

Answer (score 0):

This example uses array.shift() to get and remove the first item from the assetid array.

```js
var fakeCart = [];
var manager = {
  createOffer: function(thing) {return {addMyItem: function(obj) { fakeCart.push(obj) }};}
}
var steamID = "fake";

var items = {
        "Scrap Metal": {
            "market_hash_name": "Scrap Metal",
            "appid": 440,
            "contextid": "2",
            "assetid": [
                "6090807122",
                "6090807127",
                "6090807143",
                "6090807132",
                "6090807183",
                "6090807173",
                "6090807167",
                "6090807160",
                "6090807154"
            ]
        }
    };

var cart = {
    "Scrap Metal": 2,
};

var offer = manager.createOffer(steamID);
for (var key in cart) {
  for (var i=0; i < cart[key]; i++) {
    if (items[key] && items[key].assetid.length) {
      offer.addMyItem({
        assetid: items[key].assetid.shift(),
        appid: items[key].appid,
        contextid: items[key].contextid
      });
    } else {
      console.log("I don't have the item " + key);
    }
  }
}

console.log(fakeCart);
```